# CORS SpringBoot 2.1.2 Not Sending access control headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors, swagger

Thank you for any assistance you may provide.

This seems simple enough, I have done it before but... I am thus far unable to get CORS access control headers in my request responses.

I would like to use the global configuration option as that allows finite control to the using party over their endpoints.
I have tried using the @CrossOrigin annotation for debugging, it also does not seem to return the headers.

I have a two controllers (there are more but they are not what I need to work on right now)

1. A status controller with 2 GET endpoints

   - /health
   - /healthcheck
2. An Upload controller with 1 POST endpoint

   - /upload

I have read the various ways to fix the issue and implement cors correctly (we are not using spring security). The code compiles and executes fine unless cross origin. Specifically, we use swagger to annotate our code, when I try to use swagger to test an endpoint it will fail with a generic CORS error.

An OPTIONS request using Postman returns:

```
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
```

but none of the access control headers

So onto the code:

CorsConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource ("classpath:cors.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties (CorsProperties.class)
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final CorsProperties corsProperties;

    public CorsConfig(CorsProperties corsProperties) {
        this.corsProperties = corsProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        for (CorsModel model : corsProperties.getModels()) {
            for (String mapping : model.getEndpoints()) {
                registry.addMapping(mapping)
                        .allowedMethods(removeInputQuotes(model.getAllowedMethods()))
                        .allowedHeaders(removeInputQuotes(model.getAllowedHeaders()))
                        .allowedOrigins(removeInputQuotes(model.getAllowedOrigins()))
                        .allowCredentials(false)
// this is a test, adding exposedHeaders did not seem to do anything
                        .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
                        .maxAge(32600);
            }
        }
    }

    private String[] removeInputQuotes(List<String> input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
            input.set(i, input.get(i).replace("\"", "").replace("'", ""));
        }
        return input.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

When debugging the above, everything seems to be injected correctly, e.g. all variables are set.

CorsProperties.java

```
@ConfigurationProperties (prefix = "cors", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class CorsProperties {
    public List<CorsModel> models;

    public List<CorsModel> getModels() {
        return models;
    }

    public void setModels(List<CorsModel> models) {
        this.models = models;
    }
}
```

CorsModel.java

```
public class CorsModel {
    private List<String> endpoints;
    private List<String> allowedOrigins;
    private List<String> allowedHeaders;
    private List<String> allowedMethods;

    public List<String> getEndpoints() {
        return endpoints;
    }

    public void setEndpoints(List<String> endpoint) {
        this.endpoints = endpoint;
    }

    public List<String> getAllowedOrigins() {
        return allowedOrigins;
    }

    public void setAllowedOrigins(List<String> allowedOrigins) {
        this.allowedOrigins = allowedOrigins;
    }

    public List<String> getAllowedHeaders() {
        return allowedHeaders;
    }

    public void setAllowedHeaders(List<String> allowedHeaders) {
        this.allowedHeaders = allowedHeaders;
    }

    public List<String> getAllowedMethods() {
        return allowedMethods;
    }

    public void setAllowedMethods(List<String> allowedMethods) {
        this.allowedMethods = allowedMethods;
    }
}
```

cors.properties

```
cors.models[0].allowed-headers=*
cors.models[0].allowed-methods=GET,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD
cors.models[0].allowed-origins=*
cors.models[0].endpoints[0]=/health
cors.models[0].endpoints[1]=/healthcheck
cors.models[0].endpoints[2]=/swagger**
cors.models[0].endpoints[3]=/upload
```

FileController.java

```
@RestController
public class FileController {
    @RequestMapping (path = "/upload", method = {RequestMethod.POST},
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> upload(@RequestPart ("files") 
    List<MultipartFile> trackFiles) {
    // code to execute, this is an example, I cannot show the internals of this method
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

StatusController.java

```
@RestController
public class StatusController {
   @GetMapping (value = "/health", produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<HealthCheckResponse> health() {
        RuntimeMXBean rb = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(rb.getUptime(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

If you've gotten this far, thank you!
Alright, for the part I seem to not understand...

I want to curl the endpoints and see the access control headers in the response

```
curl -I http://localhost:8080/health
curl -I http://localhost:8080/upload
etc...
```

The curl response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 04 Nov 2021 16:40:48 GMT
```

From what I can gather, this is not correct... It should look something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Date: Thu, 04 Nov 2021 16:55:38 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: *
```

What am I missing? Aside from taking a hail Mary and injecting spring security hoping that will work.

Comment: are you using springsecurity?

Answer (score 0):

After spending much, much longer on this then I ever hoped to admit... I found a solution that incorporates the Cors Filtering into both interceptors and Filters.

Adding this to a Configuration bean will setup cors without the need to inject MVC everywhere.

```
@Bean
    @Order(1)
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        for (CorsModel model : corsProperties.getModels()) {
            for (String mapping : model.getEndpoints()) {
                final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
                configuration.setAllowedOrigins(removeInputQuotes(model.getAllowedOrigins()));
                configuration.setAllowedMethods(removeInputQuotes(model.getAllowedMethods()));
                configuration.setAllowedHeaders(removeInputQuotes(model.getAllowedHeaders()));
                configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                configuration.setMaxAge(32600L);
                configuration.setExposedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("Authorization"));
                source.registerCorsConfiguration(mapping, configuration);
            }
        }
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```

My main CorsConfig.java class now looks like:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource ("classpath:cors.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties (CorsProperties.class)
public class CorsConfig {

    private final CorsProperties corsProperties;

    public CorsConfig(CorsProperties corsProperties) {
        this.corsProperties = corsProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        for (CorsModel model : corsProperties.getModels()) {
            for (String mapping : model.getEndpoints()) {
                final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
                configuration.setAllowedOrigins(removeInputQuotes(model.getAllowedOrigins()));
                configuration.setAllowedMethods(removeInputQuotes(model.getAllowedMethods()));
                configuration.setAllowedHeaders(removeInputQuotes(model.getAllowedHeaders()));
                configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                configuration.setMaxAge(32600L);
                configuration.setExposedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("Authorization"));
                source.registerCorsConfiguration(mapping, configuration);
            }
        }
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    private List<String> removeInputQuotes(List<String> input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
            input.set(i, input.get(i).replace("\"", "").replace("'", ""));
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```